# How do I preprocess and tokenize a TensorFlow CsvDataset inside the map method?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, tensorflow-datasets

I made a TensorFlow `CsvDataset`, and I'm trying to tokenize the data as such:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import os
os.chdir('/home/nicolas/Documents/Datasets')

fname = 'rotten_tomatoes_reviews.csv'


def preprocess(target, inputs):
    tok = Tokenizer(num_words=5_000, lower=True)
    tok.fit_on_texts(inputs)
    vectors = tok.texts_to_sequences(inputs)
    return vectors, target


dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(filenames=fname,
                                          record_defaults=[tf.int32, tf.string],
                                          header=True).map(preprocess)
```

Running this, gives the following error:

> ValueError: len requires a non-scalar tensor, got one of shape Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(0,), dtype=int32)

**What I've tried**: just about anything in the realm of possibilities. Note that everything runs if I remove the preprocessing step.

What the data looks like:

```
(<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b" Some movie critic review...">)
```

Comment: Did the answer below resolve your issue? If so, please click the checkmark next to the answer to mark your question as "answered"; otherwise, please provide some feedback on the answer so that we can help you better.

Comment: This project is currently on hold. When it is resumed, I'll certainly get back to you, as this issue is still pending.

Comment: Well since you asked for feedback, I'd say that your answer is way too complicated.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As far as I know and understand, you can't integer-encode some texts without knowing the token-index mapping beforehand. To construct that mapping, you first need to construct the vocabulary/dictionary. And also, as I am writing this, there is no built-in tokenizer in TF which would be compatible with `tf.data.Dataset` and is able to do all of this in one line of code. That's what I know (for your information, as I checked now, the [TF tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/text) also use the same approach).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, let's find out the problems in your code:

- The first problem, which is also the reason behind the given error, is that the `fit_on_texts` method accepts a list of texts, not a single text string. Therefore, it should be: `tok.fit_on_texts([inputs])`.
- After fixing that and running the code again, you would get another error: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'lower'`. This is due to the fact that the elements in the dataset are Tensor objects, and the map function should be able to handle them; however, the `Tokenizer` class is not designed to handle Tensor objects (there is a fix for this problem, but I won't address it now because of the next problem).
- The biggest problem is that each time the map function, i.e. `preprocess`, is called, a new instance of `Tokenizer` class is created and it would be fit on a single text document. **Update:** As [@Princy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9808917/princy) correctly pointed out in the comments section, the `fit_on_texts` method actually performs a partial fit (i.e. updates or augments the internal vocabulary stats, instead of starting from scratch). So if we create the `Tokenizer` class outside the `preprocess` function and **assuming the vocabulary set is known beforehand** (otherwise, you can't filter the most frequent words in a partial fit scheme unless you have or build the vocabulary set first), then it would be possible to use this approach (i.e. based on `Tokenizer` class) after applying the above fixes as well. However, personally, I prefer the solution below.

---

So, what should we do? As mentioned above, in almost all of the models which deal with text data, we first need to convert the texts into numerical features, i.e. encode them. For performing encoding, first we need a vocabulary set or a dictionary of tokens. Therefore, the steps we should take are as follows:

1. If there is a pre-built vocabulary available, then skip to the next step. Otherwise, tokenize **all** the text data first and build the vocabulary.
2. Encode the text data using the vocabulary set.

For performing the first step, we use [`tfds.features.text.Tokenizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/text/Tokenizer) to tokenize text data and build the vocabulary by iterating over the dataset.

For the second step, we use [`tfds.features.text.TokenTextEncoder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/features/text/TokenTextEncoder) to encode the text data using the vocabulary set built in previous step. Note that, for this step we are using `map` method; however, since `map` only functions in graph mode, we have wrapped our `encode` function in `tf.py_function` so that it could be used with `map`.

Here is the code (please read the comments in the code for additional points; I have not included them in the answer because they are not directly relevant, but they are useful and practical):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from collections import Counter

fname = "rotten_tomatoes_reviews.csv"
dataset = tf.data.experimental.CsvDataset(filenames=fname,
                                          record_defaults=[tf.int32, tf.string],
                                          header=True)

# Create a tokenizer instance to tokenize text data.
tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()

# Find unique tokens in the dataset.
lowercase = True  # set this to `False` if case-sensitivity is important.
vocabulary = Counter()
for _, text in dataset:
    if lowercase:
       text = tf.strings.lower(text)
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text.numpy())
    vocabulary.update(tokens)

# Select the most common tokens as final vocabulary set.
# Note: if you want all the tokens to be included,
# set `vocab_size = len(vocabulary)` instead.
vocab_size = 5000
vocabulary, _ = zip(*vocabulary.most_common(vocab_size))

# Create an encoder instance given our vocabulary set.
encoder = tfds.features.text.TokenTextEncoder(vocabulary,
                                              lowercase=lowercase,
                                              tokenizer=tokenizer)

# Set this to a non-zero integer if you want the texts
# to be truncated when they have more than `max_len` tokens.
max_len = None

def encode(target, text):
    text_encoded = encoder.encode(text.numpy())
    if max_len:
        text_encoded = text_encoded[:max_len]
    return text_encoded, target

# Wrap `encode` function inside `tf.py_function` so that
# it could be used with `map` method.
def encode_pyfn(target, text):
    text_encoded, target = tf.py_function(encode,
                                          inp=[target, text],
                                          Tout=(tf.int32, tf.int32))
    
    # (optional) Set the shapes for efficiency.
    text_encoded.set_shape([None])
    target.set_shape([])

    return text_encoded, target

# Apply encoding and then padding.
# Note: if you want the sequences in all the batches 
# to have the same length, set `padded_shapes` argument accordingly.
dataset = dataset.map(encode_pyfn).padded_batch(batch_size=3,
                                                padded_shapes=([None,], []))

# Important Note: probably this dataset would be used as input to a model
# which uses an Embedding layer. Therefore, don't forget that you
# should set the vocabulary size for this layer properly, i.e. the
# current value of `vocab_size` does not include the padding (added
# by `padded_batch` method) and also the OOV token (added by encoder).
```

**Side note for future readers:** notice that the order of arguments, i.e. `target, text`, and the data types are based on the OP's dataset. Adapt as needed based on your own dataset/task (although, at the end, i.e. `return text_encoded, target`, we adjusted this to make it compatible with expected format of `fit` method).

Comment: That's actually a fantastic answer. You're most welcome to answer anytime I ask. Congrats on all your [tag:keras] points.

Comment: Thank you @today,  BTW, what if `dataset =.batch(batch_size)` is before `.map`, In that case, we will have an array of objects. How should I modify your answer, I tried using lambda but not much success.

Comment: @HARSHNILESHPATHAK Actually, it does not make sense to me to do batching before calling `map`. We first process/transform our data to make it ready, and then use batching as the final step. But if that's the otherwise in your code for a particular reason, then as you mentioned the input to the `map` function would be an array of samples; so you need to modify the `map` function to iterate over that array and process them.

Comment: @today - any ideas on how to use this technique on a dataset with multiple feature columns? Would love some input on this question if you know a good solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926554/referencing-and-tokenizing-single-feature-column-in-multi-feature-tensorflow-dat

Comment: One major WRONG INFO in the answer is this statement: "However, as the name of `fit_on_texts` method suggests, this is designed for applying it on all the text documents only once." This is wrong. It can be easily shown with a simple example that a `Tokenizer` instance updates the vocabulary as you fit more text. Moreover, the documentation also explicitly stated this for the `fit_on_texts` method: "**Updates** internal vocabulary based on a list of texts."

Comment: @Princy Thanks a lot for pointing this out. I am not sure why I assumed that each time `fit_on_texts` is called, the whole state of `Tokenizer` instance would be reset. It seems that's not true as you suggested. I have fixed my answer to reflect this point.

Comment: @today You may have mistakenly confused it with the `TextVectorization` class (very similar role as the `Tokenizer` class, but with some critical caveats), which can only be called once (its `adapt` method). Each new call of `adapt` starts everything afresh.