# Applying function to feature, Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am attempting to apply an exiting function to a TensorFlow Dataset but running into some issues with the proper way to reference a feature column. If there is just one input, the function works as expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from collections import Counter
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences


text = ["I played it a while but it was alright. The steam was a bit of trouble."
        " The more they move these game to steam the more of a hard time I have"
        " activating and playing a game. But in spite of that it was fun, I "
        "liked it. Now I am looking forward to anno 2205 I really want to "
        "play my way to the moon.",
        "This game is a bit hard to get the hang of, but when you do it's great."]


df = pd.DataFrame({"text": text})

dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
        tf.cast(df.text.values, tf.string)))

tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()

lowercase = True
vocabulary = Counter()
for text in dataset:
    if lowercase:
        text = tf.strings.lower(text)
    tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(text.numpy())
    vocabulary.update(tokens)

vocab_size = 5000
vocabulary, _ = zip(*vocabulary.most_common(vocab_size))

max_len = 15
max_sent = 5
encoder = tfds.features.text.TokenTextEncoder(vocabulary,
                                              lowercase=True,
                                              tokenizer=tokenizer)

def encode(text):
    sent_list = []
    sents = tf.strings.split(text, sep=". ").numpy()
    if max_sent:
        sents = sents[:max_sent]
    for sent in sents:
        text_encoded = encoder.encode(sent.decode())
        if max_len:
            text_encoded = text_encoded[:max_len]
            sent_list.append(pad_sequences([text_encoded], max_len))
    if len(sent_list) < 5:
        sent_list.append([tf.zeros(max_len) for _ in range(5 - len(sent_list))])
    return tf.concat(sent_list, axis=0)

def encode_pyfn(text):
    [text_encoded] = tf.py_function(encode, inp=[text], Tout=[tf.int32])
    return text_encoded

dataset = dataset.map(encode_pyfn).batch(batch_size=2)

next(iter(dataset))
```

But when I attempt to apply the same function on a single feature column resulting from a `make_csv_dataset`:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from collections import Counter
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
import numpy as np

text = ["I played it a while but it was alright. The steam was a bit of trouble."
        " The more they move these game to steam the more of a hard time I have"
        " activating and playing a game. But in spite of that it was fun, I "
        "liked it. Now I am looking forward to anno 2205 I really want to "
        "play my way to the moon.",
        "This game is a bit hard to get the hang of, but when you do it's great."]
target = [0, 1]
gender = [1, 0]
age = [45, 35]



df = pd.DataFrame({"text": text,
                   "target": target,
                   "gender": gender,
                   "age": age})

df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)

dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    'test.csv',
    batch_size=2,
    label_name='target',
    num_epochs=1)

tokenizer = tfds.features.text.Tokenizer()

lowercase = True
vocabulary = Counter()
for features, _ in dataset:
    text = features['text']
    if lowercase:
        text = tf.strings.lower(text)
    for t in text:
        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(t.numpy())
        vocabulary.update(tokens)
        
vocab_size = 5000
vocabulary, _ = zip(*vocabulary.most_common(vocab_size))

max_len = 15
max_sent = 5
encoder = tfds.features.text.TokenTextEncoder(vocabulary,
                                              lowercase=True,
                                              tokenizer=tokenizer)

def encode(text):
    sent_list = []
    sents = tf.strings.split(text, sep=". ").numpy()
    if max_sent:
        sents = sents[:max_sent]
    for sent in sents:
        text_encoded = encoder.encode(sent.decode())
        if max_len:
            text_encoded = text_encoded[:max_len]
            sent_list.append(pad_sequences([text_encoded], max_len, padding='post'))
    if len(sent_list) < 5:
        sent_list.append([tf.zeros(max_len) for _ in range(5 - len(sent_list))])
    return tf.concat(sent_list, axis=0)

def encode_pyfn(features, targets):
    features['text'] = tf.py_function(encode, inp=features[text], Tout=[tf.int32])
    return features, targets

dataset = dataset.map(encode_pyfn)

next(iter(dataset))
```

it raises the following:

```
TypeError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-9-30172a796c2e>:69 encode_pyfn  *
        features['text'] = tf.py_function(encode, inp=features[text], Tout=[tf.int32])
    /Users/username/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:823 __hash__
        raise TypeError("Tensor is unhashable. "

    TypeError: Tensor is unhashable. Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.
```

What is the proper way to apply the function to a single feature?

Comment: You probably meant writing `features['text']` (i.e. adding single quotes) here `inp=features[text]` :)

Comment: @today - thanks for the catch! Making the edit changes the error message to ` TypeError: Expected list for 'input' argument to 'EagerPyFunc' Op, not Tensor("args_2:0", shape=(), dtype=string).` I tried unbatching (suggestion from the other question) but the error remained. Any thoughts?

Comment: `inp` should be a list of Tensors, so it should be `inp=[features['text']]`.

Comment: Besides that, since you are not using unbatching here, you are working on batch of samples; hence, make sure you have considered that point in the implementation of `encode` function.

Comment: @scribbles, Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share executable code to replicate your issue. Thanks!